# How to disable RSpec in TravisCI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, travis-ci

I use Rails 5 and  Feature Tests with RSpec/Capybara/Poltergeist/Selenium. Locally the tests run fine after i manually installed the necessary geckodriver.

But on TravisCI the RSpec Tests fails with the error message:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:

Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver. Please download the server from   
   https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and place it   
 somewhere on your PATH. More info at 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver.
```

Is there an option to skip RSpec feature tests only? Or how can I configure TravisCI to use geckodriver?

Comment: Have you tried adding 
`addons:
  firefox: "50.0"`

 to your `.travis.yml` file?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. But now my feature spec is failing on TravisCI: NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `new_user_registration_path' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Signup:0x000000021bb1b8>
It seems that TravisCI doesn't use the spec/rails_helper.rb where i defined to use the url-helpers:   config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

Comment: You'd need `config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` in the `RSpec.configure do |config|`-block in `rspec_helper.rb`

Comment: yeah, i have it already so that Capybara is working fine locally. But the issue persist on TravisCI.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out a way to configure geckodriver in TravisCI for Integration Tests but at least I can specify which tests to run with:

```
env:
  - TEST_SUITE=controllers
  - TEST_SUITE=models
script: "bundle exec rake spec:$TEST_SUITE"
```

so all feature tests are skipped and my complete .travis.yml looks like this:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.2.2
services:
  - postgresql
before_script:
  - psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres
  - cp config/database.yml.travis config/database.yml
bundler_args: --without production
env:
  - TEST_SUITE=controllers
  - TEST_SUITE=models

script: "bundle exec rake spec:$TEST_SUITE"
```